# flutter Build failed with error in LayerLink

Tags: flutter, build

I'm trying to run an existing flutter projet: I got this error :

```
Error: The getter 'leader' isn't defined for the class 'LayerLink'.../…/rendering/layer.dart:54
- 'LayerLink' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/layer.dart').
```

Flutter sdk was 2.8,  I tried to update it to 2.16 and migrate the project to null safety but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the entire `LayerLink` declaration.

Comment: @lepsch Layerlink is a predefined class from package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart

Comment: [`LayerLink.leader` have been removed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/92598) since Flutter version 2.8. So, it looks like your Flutter installation is mixed with the old installation somehow. Can you try removing it completely and then reinstalling? Also, check your environment variables for old installations and then restart the IDE/Terminal so the environment variables are updated.